# Give the code below, I was told that if a hash is called and pass through as argument, I can't return Nil. Can anyone explain to me how come?

Tags: ruby

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash) 

name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v}[0] 

end
```

This was my code to fulfill the test suite for finding the lowest value of a hash (this was for one of my lessons online).

I know there are much easier ways to do this but I had some restrictions, as you can see below:

**A Few Restrictions:
We want you to build this on your own. Some of the following methods are helpful but off limits for this exercise. (We'll cover a few below in more depth in subsequent lessons).

I could not use keys, values, min, sort, min_by to make it pass.

This code returned the key with the lowest value (a hash of key ==> integers) but here was the requirement I could not figure out.

**If the method is called and passed an argument of an empty hash, it should return nil.**

Only first month programming, so this may be obvious but is there a way to return nil for an empty hash, and keep my existing code intact?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there something wrong with `return nil if name_hash.empty?`?

Comment: You probably can't use Hash#max_by, either. Regarding your main question, you just need to add a test at the top of your function that returns if the hash is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a beginner programmer I would recommend to print all intermediate results of expressions, or work in IRB.

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
    puts
    puts "in key_for_min_value with parameter #{name_hash}"
#    puts "about to return nil" if name_hash.empty?
#    return nil if name_hash.empty?

    name_hash.max_by { | item | puts "item=#{item}" }

    max = name_hash.max_by do | k, v | 
        puts "k=#{k}  v=#{v}  0 - v = #{0 - v}"
        0 - v
    end
    puts "max=#{max.inspect}, class of value returned by max_by : #{max.class}"

    result = name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v}[0]
    puts "result=#{result.inspect}"
    result
end

key_for_min_value({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})
key_for_min_value({})
```

Execution :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 

in key_for_min_value with parameter {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
item=[:a, 1]
item=[:b, 2]
item=[:c, 3]
k=a  v=1  0 - v = -1
k=b  v=2  0 - v = -2
k=c  v=3  0 - v = -3
max=[:a, 1], class of value returned by max_by : Array
result=:a

in key_for_min_value with parameter {}
max=nil, class of value returned by max_by : NilClass
t.rb:15:in `key_for_min_value': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from t.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

The documentation of `enum.max_by` says :

> Returns the item corresponding to the largest value returned by the
>   block.

But if the enum is empty, it returns `nil`, from which you fetch element `[0]`, which causes the error because there is no such method in the NilClass.

If you add `return nil if name_hash.empty?` at the beginning of the method, you prevent it to happen (with two uncommented lines) :

```
$ ruby -w t.rb 

in key_for_min_value with parameter {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
...    
in key_for_min_value with parameter {}
about to return nil
```

Comment: Hey Bernard, thanks for the response.  I am familiar with using the IRB but not at the extent that you just did.  Did you basically just create a test for my line of code?

Comment: Do you mean an RSpec test or similar ? In theory we should always start writing a test, but in this case no, I just wanted to show how you can break down the steps to understand why `[0]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of different possibilities to do what you want. The most obvious one is to literally translate the sentence: "return `nil` if the hash is empty" into Ruby:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  return nil if name_hash.empty?
  name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v}[0]
end
```

Another possibility would be to use the safe navigation operator:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v}&.[](0)
end
```

Yet another way would be to ensure that the value you are trying to index into is never `nil`:

```
def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  (name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v} || [])[0]
end

# or

def key_for_min_value(name_hash)
  Array(name_hash.max_by {|k, v| 0-v})[0]
end
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the safe navigation operator `&.` only works in Ruby versions 2.3.0 and up.

Comment: What... that is beautifully simple, and frustratingly easy haha.  Thanks for letting me know!  I did it another way, which had to do with a if/else statement, and it just was not as cool/pretty as that first line.